# Change row height of ExtendedCalendarView

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and using [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView).
I want to change height of ExtendedCalendarView.
Can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of `layout_height` to what you want:

```
<com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView 
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

eg:

```
<com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView 
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```